# Web Application Asp.Net: Execute a Dos Command

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, command

I have a web application where I want to send commands to a command line (commands are not known). This is the method I use

```
    public static string ExecuteCommand(string command)
    {
        String result;
        try
        {
            //Create a new ProcessStartInfo
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
            //Settings
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            //Create new Process
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            //Set ProcessStartInfo
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            //Start Process
            proc.Start();
            //Wait to exit
            proc.WaitForExit();
            //Get Result
            result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            //Return
            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The command works on a console application but not on a web application (null is returned)

```
    public string test = "NOTHING";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test = AppCommandHandler.ExecuteCommand("mkdir test2");
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Every tutorial I look at tells me to use `ProcessStartInfo`

**Edit** I keep getting this error:

> {"StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started
>   yet."}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the web app's pool have enough permissions to execute this command?

Comment: Let me look up how to check that and Ill get back to you

Comment: Check what account the App Pool for your website is running under IIS. I would guess only "Local Process" would be able to execute command line stuff (?).

Comment: Yea, that was the issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that like this but you've to do this with using java directly, just see the link:

[Run a cmd command with asp dotnet app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235808/how-to-run-a-cmd-exe-command-from-an-asp-net-application)