# How to run a CMD.exe command from an ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, cmd, iis-7.5

Here's my code:

```
string ex = "java -jar \"" + Settings.ClosureCompilerJarLocation + "\" --js \"" + C2runtimePath + "\" --js_output_file \"" + C2runtimeCompiledPath + "\" --language_in ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --externs \"" + Settings.C2ExternsFolderLocation + "jquery-externs.js\" --externs \"" + Settings.C2ExternsFolderLocation + "c2-externs.js\"";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", ex);
```

And an example of `ex` printed just before it executes:

> java -jar
>   "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ScirraNew\static\ac\closure-compiler\compiler.jar"
>   --js "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\arcade\games\46/c2runtime.js" --js_output_file "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\arcade\games\46/c2runtime_COMPILED.js"
>   --language_in ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --externs
>   "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ScirraNew\static\ac\templates\jquery-externs.js"
>   --externs "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ScirraNew\static\ac\templates\c2-externs.js"

- It doesn't throw any errors and doesn't complete the command
- If  I copy + paste the command into cmd.exe myself it runs just fine

Comment: There's no point in using `cmd`; you should invoke `java.exe` directly.

Comment: I believe you need to use the `/c` argument to specify the java command.  `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c \"java.exe ...\"");`

Comment: @Slaks, thanks!  But how do I do this?  I'm a total newbie on this

Comment: @Slaks, figured it out!  YOUR A GENIOUS! Thanks :D

Comment: You're calling `cmd` with a long argument.  Instead, call `java` with the argument you want to pass to `java`.

Comment: @Slaks if you put it into an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `WaitForExit()` on the resultant `Process` instance.

Comment: Thanks, still doing nothing and not throwing an error though.  I've seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679561/system-diagnostics-process-start-not-work-fom-an-iis But can't find what process to do it with on IIS 7.5 if this would help?

Comment: Calling `cmd` with that argument is wrong.  Either call `java.exe` directly or add `/c`, as noted in the comments on the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should execute `java.exe` directly, with the desired arguments.

Passing `cmd.exe` a command line won't do anything.